# How do I persist data to storage from a block driver in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to implement a block device driver in the Linux kernel (version 6.2). This is a university project, and I need to implement a redundancy scheme which will be added to another tool for use. The redundancy scheme is based on creating parity blocks based on actual data blocks (with the help of the XOR operation), and persisting everything in storage so that data corruption can be repaired. The scheme should work on 4096-byte blocks.

My question is this: How do I actually persist a block of memory to the storage device from my code? I found resources online, and some example code (like from the LDD3 book), but as far as I understood the implementations there are for a ram-disk, i.e. the memory that is intercepted in requests is not persisted to storage.

I started writing some code, and I have some baseline done for the block driver, but I am confused about the fact of how to persist data. As far as I understood, I should intercept read/write requests (from the request queue) which contain bios, do the work I need to do, and persist the blocks on the device. I found that calling submit_bio() does the trick, however doesn't this just send the request to the request_queue, which I then intercept again and again, thus creating a bad recursion?

I am probably missing something, as I am by no means an expert on the Linux kernel, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can download and study the whole kernel code.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not rely on or use the "*BIOS*". "*How do I actually persist a block of memory to the storage device*" -- That sounds like a write operation. There aren't many choices. There's a read operation, and there's a write operation. Those are the basic block operations; some devices (e.g. raw NAND flash) have a few more choices.

Comment: The "bios" word in my question is the plural of bio, as in a bio request (struct bio in the linux source code). Sorry for the misunderstanding. It is a basic write, however as I am writing a block driver, I was looking for some specific functions I can call that are available in the linux source code. I may have missed something obvious, but calling submit_bio() is wrong I believe.

Comment: I definitely do not know enough to answer this, but as per your statement: *"doesn't this just send the request to the request_queue, which I then intercept again and again"* - well, you can use the `bi_private` field of `struct bio` to simply record whether you already handled that request or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out I was looking at the problem all wrong. For what I need, I do not need to create a whole new block device driver, but rather just a new device-mapper. The device-mapper will intercept bio requests and there I can do what I want regarding my redundancy implementation, and it just uses the block device implementation already in the Linux kernel source code.

Big thanks to everyone who has taken the time to answer my question!